# Watson Knowledge Studio - Unable to load document when checking conflict

Tags: watson-knowledge-studio

When I check for conflict, after clicking Resume button under Action column, a pop-up alert shows that unable to load the document. But I can open it when viewing any annotator's list of annotation tasks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBEcU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your situation but couldn't.